# Ansible task : Getting template error while templating string: expected token ':', got '}' for one of the ansible task

Tags: ansible

Below is the task:-

```
- name: Update cluster.yaml with new disk name
  set_fact:
     cluster_yaml: "{{ cluster_yaml | combine({ 'storage': {'disk_osd': cluster_yaml.storage.disk_osd + [{ocs_dev_name}]}}, recursive=True)}}"
```

### ocs_dev_name is defined in different yaml

```
ocp_clusterid: dev
tenantid: az
ocs_dev_name: sdc
```

...

Also cluster_yaml points to cluster.yaml having below

```
storage:
  disk_osd:
  - sdb
  disk_osd_size: 100Gi
```

Comment: Hi and welcome. For a quality time here, I suggest you start by reading [How to ask](/help/how-to-ask) and [Creating a minimal complete and verifiable example](/help/mcve). Good luck.

Comment: `{"something"}` is legal **set** syntax in python, but that is not accepted by jinja2; I'd guess you meant to have some value go along with your `ocs_dev_name`, which is why jinja2 is whining about the missing `:`, but no one can guess what you're trying to do there

Comment: Hi @mdaniel, hope I am clear now, please see if there's any syntactical error. Thanks

Comment: I reverted your "obfuscation" attempt because it was no longer executable (you mangled `storage` to `xyz` but did not update the `cluster_yaml` example, meaning it would now fail for a new reason. In addition, there was nothing sensitive about the original question, so it was just confusing without gain.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have an extra pair of braces in your list construction

```yaml
  set_fact:
     cluster_yaml: "{{ cluster_yaml | combine({ 'storage': {'disk_osd': cluster_yaml.storage.disk_osd + [ocs_dev_name]}}, recursive=True)}}"
```